# Detect if Custom Keyboard has been installed

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

I've read through the documentation and can't seem to find any method of how can I detect if a custom keyboard has been installed in settings>general>keyboards?

Does anyone know of any?

Comment: NDA isn't relevant to this question.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260734/are-we-permitted-to-discuss-software-under-nda-if-the-nda-is-partly-lifted

Comment: @CrimsonChris Even if it were, there is no evidence that I ever signed the NDA, I could just be asking in general... and the people that are answering could also be answering just with their knowledge without have ever coming into an NDA with Apple. :)

Comment: Couldn't agree more. Bugs me to no end when questions are flagged because the platform in question is still in beta. This question may be a suitable for a bounty.

Comment: Why do you need to know if a custom keyboard is installed? Are you sure you don't just need it's height or something?

Comment: You could force the keyboard to show _without_ user interaction. Then immediately dismiss it.

Comment: @CrimsonChris How do I force a custom keyboard to show? :o

Comment: Add a hidden `UITextView` to the view hierarchy and then call `becomeFirstResponder` on it. This will show _the currently selected_ keyboard.

Comment: @CrimsonChris That calls Apple's default iOS keyboard... I'm trying to call my custom keyboard app-extension.

Comment: You want to check if they have the keyboard installed but _not necessarily_ selected?

Comment: Looks like you could use `NSUserDefaults` to communicate between your keyboard and companion app. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24943657/can-a-custom-keyboard-extension-communicate-with-the-companion-app-at-runtime?rq=1

Comment: @CrimsonChris Yes, but in order to do that the custom keyboard must be selected hahaha! Otherwise the custom keyboard code never loads in the first place :) I am currently using NSUserDefaults to communicate haha!

Comment: You should probably update your question clarifying this. It seems you are trying to do something outside of the normal custom keyboard workflow.

Comment: @CrimsonChris Uh... how would you reword the question to be more clear? Haha!

Comment: You should clarify that you want to check if a particular keyboard has been _installed_ but **not** _selected_.

Comment: @CrimsonChris That's already what the question says?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is possible with `NSUserDefaults`. Just retrieve the `standardUserDefaults` object which contains an array of all the keyboards the user has installed for key "AppleKeyboards". Then check if the array contains the bundle identifier for your keyboard extension.

```
NSArray *keyboards = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleKeyboards"];
NSLog(@"keyboards: %@", keyboards);

// check for your keyboard
NSUInteger index = [keyboards indexOfObject:@"com.example.productname.keyboard-extension"];

if (index != NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"found keyboard");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```swift
func isKeyboardExtensionEnabled() -> Bool {
    guard let appBundleIdentifier = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier else {
        fatalError("isKeyboardExtensionEnabled(): Cannot retrieve bundle identifier.")
    }

    guard let keyboards = UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation()["AppleKeyboards"] as? [String] else {
        // There is no key `AppleKeyboards` in NSUserDefaults. That happens sometimes.
        return false
    }

    let keyboardExtensionBundleIdentifierPrefix = appBundleIdentifier + "."
    for keyboard in keyboards {
        if keyboard.hasPrefix(keyboardExtensionBundleIdentifierPrefix) {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Swift version of @Matt solution:

```swift
if let keyboards = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "AppleKeyboards") as? [String] {
    print("keyboards: \(keyboards)")
    
    if let index = keyboards.firstIndex(of: "com.example.productname.keyboard-extension") {
        print("found keyboard")
    }
}
```